# Examples of different architecture methodologies

Tags: architecture, comparison, mvc, mvvm

Is there a resource or site which illustrates building the same application (desktop or web) using several different contrasting architectures?  Such as MVP versus MVVM versus MVC, etc.  It would be very helpful to see how they look side-by-side using real-world code instead of comparing written theory to written theory.

I've often found that something can be *described* well in a book, but when you go to *implement* it, the subtleties and weaknesses of the theory become readily apparent.

Comment: An architecture is not the implementation. Implementation will always uncover details not covered by the architecture; you can't escape that.

Comment: You should not have to look far to see example of projects that had *no* architecture.  Those are the ones to fear!

Comment: @Aaron - Understood; I know there will always be that gap between theory and reality.  But seeing realities will help me understand better how each theory plays out, and which may be a better fit for what I'm planning to build.

Comment: The topic was covered in-depth in http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Java-Interfaces-Mauro-Marinilli/dp/0471486965 as far as I remember, you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caveat with this approach is that certain frameworks lend themselves to a given architecture. WPF and SL for instance lend themselves to an MVVM pattern due to the binding nature of the technologies.

Since no specific technology was mentioned you could take a look at this [thesis](http://ganymedes.lib.unideb.hu:8080/dea/bitstream/2437/85467/1/Using%20Silverlight%20and%20XAML%20in%20MVC%20MVP%20MVVM%20patterns.pdf) which attempts to compare/contrast MVC/MVP/MVVM using Silverlight.

**EDIT:**

I know you don't want theory but this [blog post](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/) is beneficial in understanding the differences across the above mentioned architectures...MVC/MVP/MVVM.